# Identify PID of a transient network connection on HP-UX 11.23

Tags: networking, process, hp-ux, pid

We've tried lsof and tcpdump to capture the PID of a process that is attempting to make connections.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

netstat -a -p will not work in hp-ux. The -p argument, is to filter by protocol, UDP, TCP, ICMP.. (view man page). In netstat linux versions is true that show the pid.

lsof not work for you? install lsof from depot, http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Sysadmin/lsof-4.83/

and run,

`# lsof -i -sTCP:LISTEN`

Answer (score 1):

There is no "-p" option for processes in HPUX netstat command. I always have lsof installed on each server for tasks like this.

You can download it from [Hpux connect](http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Sysadmin/lsof-4.87/)

Once installed, you can easy see wich process is listen in a given port:

```
lsof -i :portnumber
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used hpux

Can you run a similar command to

netstat -a -p

to show tcp sockets back to processes?